# Basic do shell script gives error in applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a basic applescript to see how things work.
This is the script:

```
set theHostName to "www.apple.com"
do shell script "ping -c1 " & theHostName
```

However, I get `Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier`.
`do shell script` always gives error even for simpler commands.

Similar command worked on other Macs without an issue.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 19H2 x86_64. How do I get this to work?

Cheers!

[image: This image shows what I am encountering]

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same error in a new user account?

Comment: Don't have **macOS Catalina** 10.15.7 but on **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6 I copied and pasted the two lines of _code_ into a new _document_ in **Script Editor** and it worked without issue. If you do the same, copy and paste from your question into a new _document_ in **Script Editor**, does it work or do you still get the _error_?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted did not throw an error on my system. This following edit should solve your problem…

```
set theHostName to "www.apple.com"
do shell script "ping -c1 " & quoted form of theHostName
```

Comment: Same error. I've edited the question to include the error I get upon executing this command.